# Is it possible to use an SSRS 2008 R2 ReportViewer Web Part in a standard Asp.Net WebForms app?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I need to build a dashboard-style web app using SSRS 2008 R2's report viewer, but my client doesn't want to purchase Sharepoint, and doesn't want any 3rd party controls beyond SSRS.

Can the SSRS 2008 R2 Report Viewer be used as a web part in a standard Asp.Net Web Form application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the sharepoint web part, but there is an ASP.NET Report Viewer control, which I have used in standard asp.net web form application. It works great.

Here's a simple walkthrough of adding the Report Viewer control to a webforms app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252123.aspx

If you are creating an actual web part application, you might have to [create the web part yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227434.aspx) to utilize the Report Viewer control. If it isn't actually a web part application, you can just use the Report Viewer control directly.

Web parts application overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhy9ewf1.aspx

Creating reusable web parts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231577.aspx